# Identifying objects in Genie Clinical System

Tags: testcomplete

I'm using TestComplete to automate an application called Genie. It's a clinical System. But, Testcomplete is not showing the objects. Any idea what could be the issue?

Tried object explorer, but objects are not displayed.

Looks like the application uses dynamic id so, object explorer is not of any help. Do you have any idea, if this application can be automated at all?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It is not clear from your question what you are asking. Be sure and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure and provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question so we can help you with a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of seeing if TC will have better visibility into an application.  [Enable MSAA](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/object-identification/msaa/index.html), [Enable Text Recognition](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/object-identification/text-recognition/index.html), and if those don't provide more visibility, you may have to use the new [OCR functionality](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/object-identification/ocr/index.html).

Good Luck testing!  If none of these help, please reach out to your sales rep and setup some time for a screen share.